# If a wsdl is not correct and my generated web reference fails doing deserialization, what options do I have?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

Using fiddler I can see that my web service calls does indeed get a response back with the correct data.

The problem is, my response object is null  i.e. the web reference makes a call and gets data back but the actual deserialization process is failing.

I googled around and it is probably the wsdl which isn't mapping to the response returned for some reason.

What options do I have if I don't have the ability to modify the wsdl?

**Update**

```
I am making the call like this:

var serviceTest = new SecretService.GetUserProfile();

SecretService.ASADataset response = serviceTest.GetUserProfile("123");

// response is null
```

When monitoring fiddler I can see the request and response.  The response has all the data I need but I'm guessing the format is not matching what VS.NET generated.

Comment: can you show how you are consuming and or creating an instance of the web reference ? can you also debug this locally and step into the code..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have updated my question with the code.  Yes I can debug it locally but I can't step into the code that makes the call, I tried and it didn't go into the source.

Comment: ok let me ask you this do can you Invoke that by testing the call when you navigate to the URL based locally when you run this it works and need to show more code like how you are using and or referencing the Response can you use the object Browser to see if GetUserProfile exist and what it's Param type really is..?

Comment: @publicstatic Could you manually able to deserialize the response data from fiddler?

Comment: @win how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

OP asks about how to deserialize xml *(from fiddler)* to object.

```
public object DeserializeObject(string xml, Type type)
{
   var xs = new XmlSerializer(type);
   var stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
   var obj = xs.Deserialize(stringReader);
   stringReader.Close();
   return obj;
}

// Usage
var serializer = new Serializer();
var response = (Response)serializer.DeserializeObject(
    responseXml, typeof(Response));
```

The worst case you can manually post to a URL and get the reponse xml like this -

```
Uri uri = new Uri(PostUrl);
var responseXml = client.UploadString(uri, requestXml);
```